# How to connect to SQL server in termux?

Tags: mysql, host, termux

I am trying to use python and SQL in termux , I have mariadb in termux , i am able to connect to it remotely from my phone(via python) with host="localhost" but i need to host SQL in termux as usual but connect to SQL from another phone/computer , any ideas ?

Things i have tried:

Created user with host same as ip
Tried with host same as ip
Created a user with host "."
Expected:
Able to connect another phone via internet or LAN to sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ngrok , ngrok tcp 3306 , i got a link with port which can be used in any device with internet to connect to my mobile , from anywhere!

Comment: Be aware that this also permits the *rest* of the internet to potentially access 3306, so consider safety precautions; strong passwords, well hardened database server, etc.

Comment: Yeah but 3306 is used only by mariadb and I'm closing ngrok as soon as I'm done , so no worries right ? And that server is just for my learning purposes